# jquery/javascript show hide content and push site to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, slidetoggle, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a fixed div to left that fills the left site (ca 20% of the total width). Its a navigation menu. To the right I have a Span with my Site content wich is scrollable.
I want to be albe to close the menu to the left, when its closed I want the width of the content span to be 100%.
I'm using Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3.
Don't know much jquery/javascript, could need a clue or a push in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have Bootstrap in picture, you can use Jquery to do the magic for you. Hide the left div using the id something like this $('.target').hide(); and than increase the width of the corresponding right div to 100% width. something like this:

if you td is

> ** td id="myRow"  /td **

than set the width to 100% using CSS :             $('#myRow').css(width,"100%");

this should work.

Comment: can you add or change class with jquery aswell? Have the them in different spans.

Comment: I think you mean $('#myRow').css("width","100%");

Comment: Yes you can change class using Jquery. This can be done using Jquery Selectors.

Comment: I've gotten this far right now:  $(document).ready(funcation(){$('#menu').click(function(){$('.sidemenu').toggle();$('.col-md-10').css("width", "100%");});});

Comment: The toggle works and it deletes the class but i want the class back when i click on it again :P

Comment: You can use the show() method. I would suggest visit the Jquery website for more details.